# Division by values in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am building a prime generator (I know, another one and probably not a very good one at that, but that is for another question.) I am using a dictionary for my collection of primes and ignoring composites by dividing by the previous primes. However it doesn't seem to be iterating properly in the final stage of the function and I get a number of incorrect results. `isWhole` is a self explanatory call to another function. This is my code where `x` = the number of primes to be generated:

```
def prime_generator(x):
    count = 2
    counter = 2

    p = {1: 2}
    while len(p) <= x:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
            continue

        test1 = (math.sqrt(count))

        if isWhole(test1) == True:
            count += 1
            continue

        for k, a in p.items():
            if count % a == 0:
                break
            else:
                p[ counter ] = count
                counter += 1
                break

        count += 1

    return p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design intent is not entirely clear, but you may be intending to have the `else` clause apply to the `for` loop rather than the `if` statement.  Try un-indenting the entire `else` clause so that it only runs if the loop terminates without hitting a `break`.

Comment: This seems to work, though I don't understand why. If ttheif statement yields true because the number is divisble by some previous number in the dictionary it should break and ignore the else. Otherwise if count is not divisible by any previous value it should execute the else.

Comment: `count` is prime iff `count % a == 0` is false for ALL values of `a`.  As written, your code decides that it is prime if the condition is false for ANY value of `a`.  You don't know until all values have been checked, which is only after the loop completes without hitting a `break`.